# Navigator.pop() canceles InkWell animation on a Drawer

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Is it my impression or when we call `Navigator.pop` on a `Drawer`, from inside a `InkWell` tap, the `InkWell` splash doesn't show at all? Is this expected behavior? Any way around it?

I want to close my `Drawer` and open a new `Route` when the user clicks the header of my `Drawer`. The code works fine, but there's no feedback for the user tap, as the InkWell around my header doesn't animate at all. If I remove the `Navigator.pop()` it shows the ink splash as expected, but of course, it doesn't close the `Drawer`.

This is a snippet of what I am doing:

```dart
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/myRoute');
            },
            child: DrawerHeader(
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick test, and works properly (iOS simulator).

[image: screencast inkwell in drawer test]

Maybe a silly point, but make sure to put Material() as parent, and check which colors you used for splash.

You can also apply a little delay to validate if it's working properly.

```
child: Material(
    child: InkWell(
        onTap: () async {
            await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
            Navigator.pop(context);
        },
        ...
```

Comment: I am testing on Android and removing the `pop` I can see the animation of the ink splash, but I will try your code and see what happens.

Comment: Oh, just one thing, try to `pop` than `pushNamed` another route, that's where the problem arises.

Comment: I think there is a popAndPushNamed() method no?

Comment: Yes, there is I forgot about it, but it didn't change the behavior.